# Cannot use Tuple class with native queries

Tags: sql, hibernate, tuples, dto, nativequery

I'm using Spring Boot `1.5.13.RELEASE` and I'm trying to use the `javax.persistence.Tuple` to receive the results from a native query, like:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(QUERY_STRING, Tuple.class);
q.setParameter(1, param1);
q.getResultList();
```

But I receive the following error on `getResultList`:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: javax.persistence.Tuple
```

Accordly with [some links](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), this should work.

So, how use the `Tuple` on native queries? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the link that you provided, It will only work if you're using Hibernate 5.2.11+ ....

Comment: I was using 5.0.12. Never thought about the version... I think this is the answer :)